# All this steps are necessary with prepared statement?

Tags: php, mysqli

All this step are corrects and necessary ?

store_result() and bind_result() togheter ?

```
<?php
if (isset($_SESSION['userID'])) {
$userID = $_SESSION['userID'];
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare(
   "SELECT usergroup, firstname FROM tbl_users WHERE userID = ? ");
$stmt->bind_param('i', $userID); 
$stmt->execute();
$stmt->store_result();
$stmt->bind_result($usergroup, $firstname);
$stmt->fetch();
$_SESSION['usergroup'] = $usergroup;
$_SESSION['firstname'] = $firstname;
$stmt->close();
}   
?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes.

But a programmer always can write a *function* to wrap all this code in, and call it in one line

```
<?php
if (isset($_SESSION['userID'])) {
    $sql = "SELECT usergroup, firstname FROM tbl_users WHERE userID = ?";
    $_SESSION['user'] = $db->getRow($sql, $_SESSION['userID']);
}
```

However, I have to admit that to write a function based on mysqli requires extraordinary skill, which renders it practically unreliazable for the most SO users. So, better switch to PDO, as it requires three times less code to handle prepared statement, than mysqli

```
<?php
if (isset($_SESSION['userID'])) {
    $stm = $pdo->prepare("SELECT usergroup, firstname FROM tbl_users WHERE userID = ?");
    $stm->execute(array(isset($_SESSION['userID']));
    $_SESSION['user'] = $stm->fetch();
}
```

Comment: Uhmmmm.. sorry but i don't understand. Where is the prepared statement in your code ?

Comment: `userID = ?` <- here. this question mark called placeholder is what actually makes your query prepared. Everything else is wrapped into function. you are probably have to learn something new from here: http://www.php.net/manual/en/functions.user-defined.php

Comment: So dont need to bind result and store result ? i'm confuse.

Comment: All right, don't read it - there is no learning material there. So, just keep your code as is

Comment: I read [link] (http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/171172/stack-overflow-technology-makes-me-write-bad-answers) and now i understand your answer. I'm sorry about that... really. I try to use your code (safemysql) but it's too much technical for me. I like too much but how you are say "i need to read many books before use it".

Comment: you aren't required to use safemysql. better take a look at PDO. it is official library and it require three times less code than mysqli